# O que fazer depois de preparar uma Model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Gostaria de entender como posso colocar em prática em algum sistema, o modelo que crio com Deep learning ou machine learning. Vejo diversos tutoriais ensinando a criar uma estrutura bem simples de deep learning, e no final trazendo resultados de aproximadamente 90% de acurracy. Entendo que "funcionou".

Mas e agora? Como usar isso? Como colocar no meu sistema esse modelo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas formas, eu diria que as duas a seguir são as mais utilizadas.

1) **API:**

Existem diversos exemplos de API's que fazem escoragem de modelos (ver: https://cloud.google.com/vision/). Cria-se um endpoint que recebe uma nova observação e retorna o valor predito pelo algoritmo.

2) **Escoragem em batch**

O modelo é escorado diariamente, por exemplo, para todas as novas observações.

Dadas essas duas maneiras existem alguns frameworks que ajudam a fazer isso sem ter que se preocupar com escalabilidade, etc. São estes:

- https://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/.
- https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/

Na prática, é mais fácil fazer uma API em qualquer linguagem para fazer isso do que usar algum framework..

Comment: Show. No caso da API do Vision, eu consigo criar os meus modelos, sem necessariamente ser relacionados a imagem?

Comment: No caso, a API do vision é um exemplo de modelo que foi disponibilizado na forma de API. A princípio, qualquer modelo pode ser disponibilizado na forma de API... Você recebe as informações que são usadas para a escoragem e devolve o resultado predito.